# How trusty is partial LVM formatting during installation?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, lvm

I have three logical volumes on a single volume group and on a single drive, straightforwardly named `ubuntu-vg-root`, `ubuntu-vg-swap` and `ubuntu-vg-home`.

I want to install a fresh Xubuntu 16.04 instead of the current installation, but to keep the data in `ubuntu-vg-home`.  I set the Ubuntu installer to format `ubuntu-vg-root` and to use `ubuntu-vg-home` on `/home` without formatting.

I know everything would go well with "standard" partitioning, but I'm not very knowledgeable about LVM : **how much can I trust the installer to *not* erase `ubuntu-vg-home` ?**

Comment: Oh, and yes, I know about backing up.  That's not the point. ;)

Comment: You can trust the installer to format what you tell it to format and to not format what you don't tell it to format. For best results, don't use the `ubuntu-vg-home` for anything, and add it to `/etc/fstab` once you have the new system up and running.

Comment: @AlexP : Indeed it worked as expected (couldn't wait any longer…).  Please make your comment an answer so that I can accept it.  And adding `ubuntu-vg-home` afterwards is good advice indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trust the installer to format what you tell it to format and to not format what you don't tell it to format. For best results, don't use the `ubuntu-vg-home` for anything, and add it to `/etc/fstab` once you have the new system up and running.

Comment: Indeed it worked as expected, and adding `ubuntu-vg-home` only afterwards is good advice.